# Joining two tables where one of them has 2 possible values

Tags: php, mysql

I except my code to give following output:

I'm trying to select some info from my users table, where the id equals "user", which i've specified in the first part where it says "as **user**". But it wont use the output from user in the part below?

Here's what i've tried:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN user_1 = '103' THEN user_2 ELSE user_1 END) as user FROM contacts
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT NULL AS user FROM users WHERE id = user   
                                        LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's kinda hard to explain...but i have edited it now.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understood your questions, but if you want to do an inner join joining on a field or another field, the easiest way is to do two separate query and an union between those.

Comment: It is supposed to first, look in my "contacts" table for anywhere user_1 or user_2 is equal to 44, then take the opposite field and search in the users table where the id is equal to the one we found in the contacts table. And last sort by the last_online column in the users table.

Comment: So why is ID 22 not on expected result list? Really want to help but couldn't get the scenario.

Comment: Okay i edited it now, since i created another way around.. but why can i not user the "AS user" in the part after "UNION ALL"